# Error 500 when I tried to load API data from Omie using http Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I am trying to get some data from Omie API, but I am only receiving error 500. Can you any error in my code?

```
Future<bool> get() async {
    final uri = Uri.parse('https://app.omie.com.br/api/v1/produtos/pedido/');
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "call": "ConsultarPedido",
      "app_key": "3********1",
      "app_secret": "3*******b",
      "param": [
        {"codigo_pedido": "9159824162"}
      ]
    };
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      uri,
      headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
      body: json.encode(data),
    );
    print('statusCode: ${response.statusCode}');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Using Postman works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your server doesn't like the `content-type` that Dart sends. As you are passing in a string as the body, `http` encodes that to bytes under the hood and changes your `content-type` automatically from `application/json` to `application/json; charset=utf8` (as it used utf8 to encode the string). Your server barfs on the encoding suffix.

The workaround is to do the encoding yourself and pass raw bytes to `http` (so that it doesn't add the encoding suffix).

Change:

```
  body: json.encode(data),
```

to

```
  body: utf8.encode(json.encode(data)),
```